Accessing /wp-admin results in 302 HTTP Forwarding to a different site
Accessing abc.com/wp-admin gets me automatically a 302 Redirect to a total different website (on the same WHM Server), the RAW Header Response looks like this.
Could not detect any malware nor something strange in .htaccess, DNS A Records of abc.com and the target point to the same WHM Server (which is correct, 2 websites, same Web Server). Note: ABC.com does not have a valid SSL Cert right now:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Sun, 13 Oct 2024 17:58:56 GMT Server: Apache Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0 X-Redirect-By: WordPress Location: https: // xyz.com / wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 Content-Length: 0 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

I see in CPanel Error Log, mocking about no index.php but there is a default WP index.php:
[Fri Oct 11 16:21:52.140985 2024] [autoindex:error] [pid 1684050:tid 1684069] [client 13.75.253.86:4754] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/abc/public_html/wordpress/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php8,index.php7,index.php5,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.jp,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.html,index.htm,index.js) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: http: // abc.com/wordpress

I scanned several times, nothing unusual. Checked WP-Config, seems normal. Check _wp_options table, also okay.

Did you check out your site URL in the database, options table? Options names: "home", "siteurl" in option_name column
